# Как отправлять сообщения в электронную почту?

Tags: email, рассылка

Как посредством PHP, отправлять сообщения на электронную почту с гарантированной доставкой, чтобы сами сообщения не попадали в спам-лист?

Comment: Ваш вопрос никак не связан с PHP. Он осуществляет доставку письма до сервера, но не проверяет вашу добросовестность.

Comment: @VenZell Не все знают эти тонкости,  потому качественный ответ от профессионала, будет полезен другим, кто не знаком с ними в полной мере.

Comment: @alexander barakin Это два разных вопроса. Почитайте.

Comment: @VenZell Вы ошибаетесь - наш вопрос, не только  с PHP связан. Попытайтесь ответить на этот вопрос, если у вас достаточно опыта. Приятного Вам дня.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отправлять через правильно настроенный SMTP сервер. Использовать [DKIM-подписи](https://yandex.ru/support/pdd/set-mail/dkim.xml) и [SFP-записи](https://yandex.ru/support/pdd/set-mail/spf.xml). Придерживаться рекомендаций по оформлению и содержанию писем, не злоупотреблять количеством писем и получателей. [Тестировать письма](http://vpsvds.ru/blog/2015/11/06/proverka-pisem-na-spam.html) перед массовой рассылкой на вероятность попасть в спам-фильтр.

Comment: Спасибо, но мы нуждаемся в полноценном примере, который в полной мере демонстрирует работу этого механизма. Пожалуйста, приведите пример.

Comment: правильно настроенный SMTP сервер - как правильно настроить?